# Removing values from column within groups based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I am really struggling with this even though I feel like it should be extremely easy.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Title | Release Date | Released | In Stores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Seinfeld | 1995 |  |  |
| Seinfeld | 1999 | Yes |  |
| Seinfeld | 1999 |  | Yes |
| Friends | 2000 | Yes |  |
| Friends | 2004 |  | Yes |
| Friends | 2004 |  |  |

I am first grouping by `Title`, and then `Release Date` and then observing the values of `Released` and `In Stores`. If both `Released` and `In Stores` have a value of "Yes" in the same `Release Date` year, then remove the `In Stores` value.

So in the above dataframe, the category Seinfeld --> 1999 would have the "Yes" removed from `In Stores`, but the "Yes" would stay in the `In Stores` category for "2004" since it is the only "Yes" in the Friends --> 2004 category.

I am starting by using

```
df.groupby(['Title', 'Release Date'])['Released', 'In Stores].count()
```

But I cannot figure out the syntax of removing values from `In_Stores`.

Desired output:

| Title | Release Date | Released | In Stores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Seinfeld | 1995 |  |  |
| Seinfeld | 1999 | Yes |  |
| Seinfeld | 1999 |  |  |
| Friends | 2000 | Yes |  |
| Friends | 2004 |  | Yes |
| Friends | 2004 |  |  |

EDIT: I have tried this line given in the top comment:

```
flag = (df.groupby(['Title', 'Release Date']).transform(lambda x: (x == 'Yes').any()) .all(axis=1))
```

but the kernel runs indefinitely.

Comment: What is the intent of the groupby if you expand it again in your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby.transform` to flag rows where `In Stores` needs to be removed, based on whether the row's `['Title', 'Release Date']` group has at least one value of 'Yes' in column `Released`, and also in column `In Stores`.

```
flag = (df.groupby(['Title', 'Release Date'])
          .transform(lambda x: (x == 'Yes').any())
          .all(axis=1))

print(flag)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

df.loc[flag, 'In Stores'] = np.nan
```

Result:

| Title | Release Date | Released | In Stores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Seinfeld | 1995 | nan | nan |
| Seinfeld | 1999 | Yes | nan |
| Seinfeld | 1999 | nan | nan |
| Friends | 2000 | Yes | nan |
| Friends | 2004 | nan | Yes |
| Friends | 2004 | nan | nan |

Comment: Thanks! The syntax and direction of these lines definitely make sense. The only problem is that the kernel is stuck on `flag = (df.groupby(['Title', 'Release Date']).transform(lambda x: (x == 'Yes').any()) .all(axis=1))` - it has been running for the last 5 minutes.